# How to build a project from github with my own gradle

Tags: github, gradle, project

I have to import project from **Github** and it take time to build so i decide to build it offline with my **Gradle** i already download it on my pc.

Comment: How should building with "your own" Gradle speed up the build? The only difference is that once the correct Gradle version needs to be downloaded if not done already by another build that uses that Gradle version. If you use another Gradle version than the wrapper of the project defined, the build might not produce the correct result.

Comment: so should i wait until android studio download old (gradle 1.9) 200MB

Comment: Gradle 1.9 has 38.2 MiB, not 200 MiB. But yes, I'd recommend doing so. It only has to do it once.

Comment: hahahahahaha ...we are in egypt and the internet is very bad you can't even imagine ,but i appreciate your answer

Comment: Well, doesn't help, you need to once do it. You can of course run with your own Gradle by simply calling `gradle` from your download instead of `gradlew` from the project, but as I said, the build might not behave as designed if you have a different version than the build is designed with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How should building with "your own" Gradle speed up the build? The only difference is that once the correct Gradle version needs to be downloaded if not done already by another build that uses that Gradle version. If you use another Gradle version than the wrapper of the project defined, the build might not produce the correct result.